# RX Subscribe called repeatedly

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I was working on a larger project which uses Rx extensively.  In one particular instance I noticed one of the subscriptions threw an exception.  At that point I assumed the subscription would just be completed (with an error) as I did not have any Retry() call.  However, what I saw was the subscription repeatedly retried.

I tried to repro a similar case in a small example, seen below.  I put a break point on

```
Console.WriteLine("!");
```

and expected it to be hit after the subscription failed.  But it is never reached. GetImportantValues().Subscribe is just called over and over.

I don't understand why though.  I would have expected the exception that is thrown to kill the subscribe attempt.

I would like to modify the below sample to retry 3 times if an exception is thrown, and then after that just stop altogether.

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace RxTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ob1 = GetImportantValues().Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

            Console.WriteLine("!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IObservable<int> GetImportantValues()
        {
            var obs = GetThem();
            return obs;
        }

        private static IObservable<int> GetThem()
        {
            //Do some work.  Would return a valid observable if everything is ok
            return Observable.Throw<int>(new Exception("test"));
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not being called over and over again. You probably just have [Break on first chance exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) enabled in Visual Studio and each time you try to continue it's just breaking on the same exception. If you were to actually continue the process the application would just crash.

`Observable.Throw` calls `OnError`. You haven't provided an `OnError` handler in your call to `Subscribe`, so the default `OnError` handler is used. The default behavior simply throws the error and brings down the process.

To retry simply apply `Retry(3)` before calling `Subscribe`. To swallow the error after the 3rd attempt, provide an `OnError` handler to `Subscribe`, though I don't necessarily recommend the latter. Think carefully whether the application can really recover from such a scenario.